# How to split MFC dialog with 3 views?

Tags: view, split, interface, mfc, dialog

**Question:** How can I split MFC dialog with 3 views?
**Environment:** Win10 RS5 x64
**Tools:** Visual Studio 10.0 + Sp1

When I executed the application, "Debug Assertion Failed!" error has occurred.

**Error Message :**

```
Debug Assertion Failed!  
File: f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\include\afxwin2.inl  
Line: 82
```

**I want to split dialog like this:**

[image]

**Implementation Code Here:**

```
// SampleDlg.h
class CSampleDlg : public CDialogEx
{
    //...
public:
    CSplitterWndEx m_wndSplitter;
};

// SampleDlg.cpp
BOOL CSampleDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    //...
    if (!m_wndSplitter.CreateStatic(this, 2, 1))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (!m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CChild_NoteView), CSize(100, 100), 0) ||
        !m_wndSplitter.CreateView(1, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CChild_LogView), CSize(100, 100), 0))
    {
        m_wndSplitter.DestroyWindow();
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

// Child_NoteView.h
class CChild_NoteView : public CView
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CChild_NoteView)
    //...
public:
    CFont           m_note_font;
    CRichEditCtrl   m_note_edit;
}

// Child_NoteView.cpp
Message : WM_CREATE
int CChild_NoteView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if(CView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    CreateNoteEdit();

    return 0;
}
VOID CChild_NoteView::CreateNoteEdit()
{
    m_note_font.CreatePointFont(80, L"Consolas");
    m_note_edit.Create(ES_MULTILINE | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL, 
        CRect(10, 10, 100, 100), this, IDD_EDIT_NOTE);
    m_note_edit.SetReadOnly(TRUE);

    m_note_edit.SetFont(&m_note_font, 1);

    return VOID();
}
```

I thought that this error occurring when I try to create empty view.
So, I implemented note edit, but still same error occurring.

Answer (score 0):

When you get these debug errors, the debugger should give you the option to view the source code (older versions of Visual Studio may give you a hard time though). You can then open *"Call stack"* window and trace the error.

In this case, the debugger is probably telling you that `CSplitterWndEx` is looking for `CFrameWnd` and can't find it.

You can derive your own class `CMySplitterWndEx` and change the code to return the main dialog instead of returning `CFrameWnd`

Alternatively, you can add a fake frame window as follows:

```
BOOL CSampleDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(&rc);

    CFrameWnd *frame = new CFrameWnd;
    CString framecls = AfxRegisterWndClass(0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    frame->Create(framecls, L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, rc, this);

    m_wndSplitter.CreateStatic(frame, 2, 1);
    m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CChild_NoteView), CSize(100, 100), NULL);
    m_wndSplitter.CreateView(1, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CChild_NoteView), CSize(100, 100), NULL);

    rc.MoveToXY(0, 0);
    m_wndSplitter.MoveWindow(rc);
    m_wndSplitter.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    return TRUE;
}
```

You may want to add `CCreateContext` as well.